# VPN client config using IPsec/L2TP using debian raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, vpn, ipsec, l2tp, strongswan

I am setting up my raspberry pi as a VPN client using IPsec/L2TP.I am using the following guide [Configure Linux VPN clients using the command line](https://github.com/hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn/blob/master/docs/clients.md)

1. There are several problems which I am encountring
   After setting up all the settings, when I try to start the IPsec connection using `ipsec up myvpn`. I get the following error

   /usr/local/sbin/ipsec: unknown IPsec command "up" ("ipsec --help" for list)
2. After setting up and rebooting my raspberry pi, when I run  `ipsec verify`, I get the table [status table of ipsec verify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGV3U.png) in which my pluto is not running(error 1) and 
   there is an error of `ikev1`.

My motivation is to setup VPN client on my raspberry pi using  **IPsec/L2TP** so that I can access my remote VPN client.
Also I am setting up my  IPsec/L2TP using `strongSwan` and `xl2tpd` but using `Ipsec verify`, on path ipsec verison is `Libreswan 3.27 (netkey) on 4.14.98-v7+`. i tried to change it but didn't succeeded.
Any recommendations regaridng above mentioned queries would be great and I shall be thanful.
Regards
Saqib